# react-native-firebase: How to delete a token at logout?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'd like to stop receiving notifications to the app once the user logs out.
I guess I'd have to remove the device token generated by react-native-firebase but I can't find any functionality to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

## [messaging().deleteToken()](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#deleteToken)

You could achieve like this:

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) // Signed out
        messaging().deleteToken();
});
```

Comment: There is a bug with this approach - on android client stops receiving notifications for next users until user removes and installs the app again.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov Hi, can u give me git detail link?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation isn't great, but I have found a working solution in `v4.3.x`

```js
// login
const authorizedEntity = firebase.iid().app.options.messagingSenderId;
firebase.iid().getToken(authorizedEntity).then(token => token);

// logout
const authorizedEntity = firebase.iid().app.options.messagingSenderId;
firebase.iid().deleteToken(authorizedEntity, '*').then(nullToken => nullToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't store Firebase token inside the app, you should store it in the database.
Firebase token is a device identifier for notifications, if someone steals it they could bomb someone with notifications.

Create a API route that handles logout (ex. POST /user/logout) on your backend, and on that request remove the firebase token from the database.

Comment: What if you logout the App while in offline?

Answer (score 1):

The firebase token is per **app instance**. The token will remain the same as long as the app is installed on the device. To remove the token you will have to uninstall the app.

To solve your problem, you should disocciate the token from the logged-in user when they log out. You can do this by sending a request to you server on user logout in order to update your database record where the token is associated with the user. Then, when a new user logs in, you should send another request to the server to associate the token with that user.